# Vue js передача данных между компонентами

Tags: vue.js

Всё перечитал. Не могу понять как передать статическое значение из одного дочернего компнента в другой. Пробовал и через $emit через родительский компонент и по-всякому. В документации пример понятен, но под свой случай подстроить его не могу.
Использую vue.cli и компонентный подход.

App.vue обычный:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="flexing">
      <questionPanel />
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firstQuestion from './components/firstQuestion'
import questionPanel from './components/questionPanel'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    first,
    questionPanel,
  },
}
</script>
```

Есть первый компонент first.vue:

```
<template>
   <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'first',
      components: {},
      props: {},
      data() {
        return {
          title: 'Текст первого вопроса',
        }
      },
    }
</script>
```

Есть второй questions.vue:

```
    <template>
            
    </template>
       
import first from './first.vue'

    <script> 
        export default {
            name: 'questions',
            components: {
              first
            },
            props: ['title'],
            data() {
                return {
                    questions: 'questions'
                }
            }
    }
    </script>
```

Как мне отобразить `title` в questions ?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Как - либо подъемом значения `title` в родительский компонент и передачей через пропсы (наиболее разумно в данном случае), либо импортом этой единственной строки через compostion (такой вариант выглядит как совершенно дурной, его даже рассматривать не стоит, имхо).

Comment: Спасибо большое, с composition ещё не знаком, но учту.

Comment: Composition API оправдан только когда есть многократно переиспользуемые "кирпичики" бизнес-логики, которые приходится дублировать с Options API. То есть, старый добрый опшнс выбрасывать конечно не надо, ведь оба подхода прекрасно работают вместе и дополняют друг друга (каждый обладает своими недостатками и достоинствами. Это по сути "декларативность vs императивность"). С переносом значения в пропсы - получилось разобраться, или есть уточнения к вопросу?

Comment: Спросил у опытного фронта, он сказал, что так делать, как я хочу - очень плохо)

Comment: Плохо сокращать дублирование значений переносом их в пропсы, или что?))